# React - Inner functions inside functional components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

We've got a discussion in our team regarding functional components and inner methods. Let me show you the example

That would be the way that one part of the team would like to use it:

```
const ShowMeComponent = () => {
  const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const onClick = () => setVisible(!isVisible)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Toggle Visibility</button>
      {isVisible && <div>I am visible!</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

That's the way other part of the team would like:

```
const onClick = (isVisible: boolean, setVisible: YouHaveToTypeIt) => (e: ClickEvent) => setVisible(!isVisible)

const ShowMeComponent = () => {
  const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const onClickClosure = onClick(isVisible,setVisible)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickClosure}>Toggle Visibility</button>
      {isVisible && <div>I am visible!</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

So in my opinion code is getting less readable, and you've got more work to do because you have to type functions that you're moving outside of the component.
I can't see any downsides of doing
`const onClick = () => setVisible(!isVisible)`

One of the arguments that they are using is that with moving functions outside of the Component you can easily unit test them. But shouldn't we treat a Component as an Unit? Also in the documentation I can't see anything bad related to methods inside functional components.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Best Regards

Comment: Well, `setVisible(!isVisible)` is not even correct way to change state depending on current state. You need to use callback version `setVisible(visible => !visible)`. :) This approach will allow you to move mutation function outside of the component `const toggle = visible => !visible` and unit test it. In general you should not change your code to test it. And usually you don't want to test implementation details like component internal state and handlers, you want to test component behaviour: ie user clicks div toggles.

Comment: I totally agree that changing the code for testing, and making it less readable is silly. So you agree that we should treat component as Unit?

Comment: Totally. But in case state changing function is complex enough to make it a separate unit you can extract it from the component and test.

Answer (score 0):

I this the former one is more appropriate than the latter one. You are right, a component should be considered a single unit while testing.

The latter one is not just less readable but also in disambiguation and would lead to memory leak problem, if not handled quite well. After all, you are using the setVisible method of a class without making its object.

Comment: Could you tell me more about memory leak?

Comment: You are using setVisible outside the component in which it is declared.  This way, anyone can manually assign the value through the method and would lead to disaster. That's why until the setVisible method is being called from inside of the class itself, it would be dangerous to work. Its not a good practice and is never recommended dou to this risk factor.